# error in printing the specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to print a specified div or table and its works fine in a test file. but when i write the exact code snippet in my original page its saying that document.getElementById('printable') is returning null..
i know what that means..that its not finding the id of my element.
So then i searched and i write $(document).ready(); and that error stopped. But due to this the whole page is printed(not the specified one). i also tried to write the script after my 'printable' div but then it gives the same null error..
Can anyone help me please. it will be appreciated.
and please try to give an answer like the below syntax, i mean dont change the whole code just tell me what im i missing. Thanks
I just wanna know why its saying null even when i write the script after the printable div and if i add ready function why it prints the whole page?

```
<head>
<script>

function print(){

var org=document.body.innerHTML;
var spc=document.getElementById("printable").innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML= spc;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML= org;


}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="printable">
<tr>Only this should be printed</tr>
</table>

<div id="print-btn">
<button onclick="print()">Print</button>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the media query `@media print`, add a class .printable to anything that should be printed and call `javascript:window.print()` with the button.

```
<head>
<style>
    @media print {
        .*{
            display: none;
        }
        .printable {
            display: block;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="printable">
    <tr><td>This should be printed</td></tr>
</table>
<p class="printable">So should this</p>
<p>But not this</p>
<div class="printable">
    <p>And all</p>
    <p>of this</p>
</div>
<div id="print-btn">
    <button onclick="javascript:window.print()">Print</button>
</div>
<script>/* by the way, this is where javascript belongs */</script>
</body>
```

Comment: i like the appraoch..but i dont know why its not working here..but i get the sense of it..Thanks..and one more question..

Comment: .*{} means all the divs that have classes??
and #*{} this means all divs that have ids???

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 1):

A better approach might be to use a css media selector to remove stuff you don't want printed. For example:

```
<head>
<style>
    @media print {
        #print-btn {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="printable">
    <tr><td>Only this should be printed</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="print-btn">
    <button onclick="javascript:window.print()">Print</button>
</div>

</body>
```

Then you can just print the page.

Also, from your example, it looks like you're redefining the window.print function with your own.
To clarify,

```
function print() {
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```
window.print = function() {
    ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't you use `*{visible:false} #printable{visible:true}` inside that query since the question says "Only this should be printed", otherwise a much better solution than using JS

Comment: @Popnoodles: Good point. I'd actually have to test that one to make sure the `*` selector doesn't override the inheritance of the `#printable` parent. Otherwise the `tr` element would need to be marked as `id="printable"` as well... using something like `#printable, *`.

Comment: i'm sorry im a newbie. i dont know how to wrok with @media print. i"ve tried but its not working. Can you write the code with respect to above example. if thats not too much to ask..

Comment: @mastermind it is CSS and belongs in a CSS file or style tag. I've updated the answer so you can apply the new code correctly.

Comment: its a good trick..but in this case i have to hide soo many divs in my page..it will be too complicated...is there a way to just set the visibility on of the desired div and set visibility hidden of everything else??

Comment: coz if i follow this i have to set the visibility hidden of more than 20 divs.

Comment: @Popnoodles i've applied your method and its working fine thanks...
but there is just a little problem, that the table i wanna print is in the middle of the page..and in the printed page its also in the middle..i want it to be on the top left corner..how can i do that??

Comment: Tony has done it the wrong way round. Add a class `.printable` to anything that should be printed, e.g. `<table class="printable">` and use this CSS instead `@media print { *{visible:false} .printable{visible:true} }` In fact, I'l post it as an answer so you can see

Answer (score 0):

The page is rendered top to bottom by the browser. When your script runs the div doesn't exist yet. Either move your script to the bottom of the body tag or use an event listener to run your script once the page loads.

js:

```
function runScripts() {
  // do your stuff
}
```

html:

```
<body onload="runScripts()">
```

Comment: i have 4,5 scripts tags in my page..and it starts executing one of them,,and takes the header to another page..